# chat bot exception: OnTurnAsync exception

Tags: botframework

After I deploy my bot to the Azure web app, the bot is working fine only for some users. But for other users, it is returning the error which is stated inside a startup.cs file, which is:

```
options.OnTurnError = async (context, exception) => {
    logger.LogError($"Exception caught : {exception}");
    await context.SendActivityAsync("Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.");
};
```

I am not sure why this is happening: any help please?

Comment: Have you tried looking where it's logging to? Have you implemented AppInsights, in which case it would log to the Exceptions list, and see what the exception is.

Comment: If any error occurs , it will be catched in this generic error function, keep a debugger and check using IDE, (or) activate appInsights and check the logs. Ok when bot is running go to the code Kudu module and check the logs .[ or check the code in online enumerator and see the logs ]

Comment: Are they getting this error on any specific channel? You can make use of [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) to debug any channel locally? Also, you can make use of Visual Studio to [diagnose the exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#diagnosing-exceptions-using-visual-studio).

Comment: yes am getting this exception

Error resolving type specified in JSON 'EthiopianBot.Models.TokenResponse, TestBot'. Path 'ChecktimeState.TokenResponse.$type', line 1, position 10772.

Comment: Are the users getting this error on any specific channel? Can you check the bot's channel health tab to see if you are getting any more detailed error?

Comment: No the error is not specific to channel. The bot is working fine for some users on telegram, but returns the above error for others. may be it is specific to the chat id.

Comment: @Alex in this case, telegram is a channel. If you can check in the 'Channels' tab under Bot management for the Health section if it show up any errors or check the exception logs on App Insights ? It is very difficult to figure out unless you are testing the bot locally and see where the code breaks in Visual Studio by setting breakpoints.

Comment: @ranusharao, the error is occurring when trying to access the user profile. here is the line where the exception shows:

var userProfile = await _accessors.UserProfileAccessor.GetAsync(turnContext, ()=>new UserProfile());

Comment: @Alex can you update your question with how you are creating the user state object and adding state property accessor? Also, are you using any specific bot sample or just implementing your own code?